# Partial expansion: macro arguments and nothing more

Tags: programming, bashful

I am in search for a package that would allow me to do write a command of the following sort:

```
\tofile{filename}{One}{Two} FROM HERE
  here is some nonsensical list of commands,
  \unexpand\expandafter\gdef\indlude{#1}\def\expand\myOtherCrazyMacro
  but who cares, I can even place my C code here
  #include <stdio.h>
  main() {
    printf("#2",\n);
  }
  this }}{{is some other illegal LaTeX code, which uses % percents, 
  & other _^^^_ ASCII stuff. 
TO THERE
```

such that everything between "FROM HERE" to "TO THERE" would appear in the filename, except that "#1" and "#2" which gets replaced by the macro arguments.

My own [`bashful`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex2e/contrib/bashful) package does something very similar, so I suppose I could hack it somehow, but I was hoping to find a ready made solution, or something more decent than the miserable hacking I did in my package.

After running this macro, the contents of the file named `filename` should be:

```
  here is some nonsensical list of commands,
  \unexpand\expandafter\gdef\indlude{One}\def\expand\myOtherCrazyMacro
  but who cares, I can even place my C code here
  #include <stdio.h>
  main() {
    printf("Two",\n);
  }
  this }}{{is some other illegal LaTeX code, which uses % percents, 
  & other _^^^_ ASCII stuff.
```

Comment: Not if you want to be able to use `#` also as a printable character. It's either the parameter indicator or a printable character, it can't be both.

Comment: This is not a real issue I think. One can live without it, or use a different place holder for the parameter. I suppose one can do a fine grained parsing to distinguish between the two contradicting meanings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `#` with a double meaning is impossible with standard methods. Here's something that seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newwrite\tofile@write
\def\tofile#1#2#3FROMHERE
 {%
  \begingroup
  \immediate\openout\tofile@write=#1\relax
  \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
  \endlinechar=`\^^J
  \@tofile{#2}{#3}%
 }
\def\TOTHERE{TOTHERE}
\def\@tofile#1#2#3^^J{%
  \def\@test{#3}%
  \ifx\@test\TOTHERE
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\endgroup}%
  {\toks@{#3}%
   \begingroup\catcode`\#=6 \endlinechar=\m@ne
   \everyeof{\noexpand}%
   \xdef\@temp##1##2{\scantokens\expandafter{\the\toks@}}%
   \endgroup
   \immediate\write\tofile@write{\@temp{#1}{#2}}%
   \@tofile{#1}{#2}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tofile{filename}{One}{Two}FROMHERE
Something \absurd{||-\for\yossi
Else #1 or #2
TOTHERE

\end{document}
```

The produced file is

```
Something \absurd{||-\for\yossi
Else One or Two
```

---

Another solution using LaTeX3 features. The opening string should be equal to the ending one and not separated from the second argument; use only printable and non (TeX) special ASCII characters. The first argument used in the example is `\jobname.txt` just not to clobber other files in my file system, you can use whatever name you want.

More substitutions could be accommodated, let me know.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\tofile}{m}
 {
  \yossi_tofile:n { #1 }
 }

\iow_new:N \g_yossi_tofile_write_stream

\cs_new_protected:Npn \yossi_tofile:n #1
 {
  \group_begin:
  \tex_endlinechar:D `\^^J
  \iow_open:Nn \g_yossi_tofile_write_stream { #1 }
  \yossi_tofile_aux:nnw
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \yossi_tofile_aux:nnw #1 #2 #3 ~%
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_yossi_eof_tl { #3 }
  \tl_trim_spaces:N \l_yossi_eof_tl
  \cs_set_eq:NN \do \char_set_catcode_other:N
  \dospecials
  \yossi_readline:nnw { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \yossi_readline:nnw #1 #2 #3 ^^J
 {
  \str_if_eq:VnTF \l_yossi_eof_tl { #3 }
   {
    \iow_close:N \g_yossi_tofile_write_stream
    \group_end:
   }
   {
    \yossi_replace_write:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
    \yossi_readline:nnw { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \yossi_replace_write:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #3 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \#1 } { #1 } \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \#2 } { #2 } \l_tmpa_tl
  \iow_now:NV \g_yossi_tofile_write_stream \l_tmpa_tl
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \iow_now:Nn { NV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_if_eq:nnTF { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\tofile{\jobname.txt}{One}{Two}<<EOF
here is some nonsensical list of commands,
\unexpand\expandafter\gdef\indlude{#1}\def\expand\myOtherCrazyMacro
but who cares, I can even place my C code here
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
  printf("#2",\n);
}
this }}{{is some other illegal LaTeX code, which uses % percents, 
& other _^^^_ ASCII stuff. 
<<EOF

\end{document}
```

This is the file that's written out:

```
here is some nonsensical list of commands,
\unexpand\expandafter\gdef\indlude{One}\def\expand\myOtherCrazyMacro
but who cares, I can even place my C code here
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
  printf("Two",\n);
}
this }}{{is some other illegal LaTeX code, which uses % percents,
& other _^^^_ ASCII stuff.
```

Thanks to Joseph Wright for suggesting replacements via regular expressions.

---

A new version, allowing any number of arguments; however they have to be specified in a different way, see the example code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\tofile}{m}
 {
  \manual_tofile:n { #1 }
 }

\iow_new:N \g_manual_tofile_write_stream
\tl_const:Nn \c_manual_specials_tl { \  \\ \{ \} \$ \& \# \^ \_ \% \~ }
\tl_new:N \l_manual_argument_tl
\tl_new:N \l_manual_line_tl
\seq_new:N \l_manual_arguments_seq
\int_new:N \l_manual_arguments_int

\cs_new_protected:Npn \manual_dospecials:
 {
  \tl_map_inline:Nn \c_manual_specials_tl
   {
    \char_set_catcode_other:N ##1
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \manual_tofile:n #1
 {
  \group_begin:
  \tex_endlinechar:D `\^^J
  \iow_open:Nn \g_manual_tofile_write_stream { #1 }
  \manual_tofile_aux:nw
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \manual_tofile_aux:nw #1 #2 ~%
 {% #1 is the list of arguments, #2 is the terminator
  \tl_set:Nn \l_manual_eof_tl { #2 }
  \tl_trim_spaces:N \l_manual_eof_tl
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_manual_arguments_seq { } { #1 }
  \int_set:Nn \l_manual_arguments_int { \seq_count:N \l_manual_arguments_seq }
  \manual_dospecials:
  \manual_readline:w
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \manual_readline:w #1 ^^J
 {
  \str_if_eq:VnTF \l_manual_eof_tl { #1 }
   {
    \iow_close:N \g_manual_tofile_write_stream
    \group_end:
   }
   {
    \manual_replace_write:n { #1 }
    \manual_readline:w
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \manual_replace_write:n #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_manual_line_tl { #1 }
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \l_manual_arguments_int }
   {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_manual_argument_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_manual_arguments_seq { ##1 } }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \# ##1 } { \u{l_manual_argument_tl} } \l_manual_line_tl
   }
  \iow_now:NV \g_manual_tofile_write_stream \l_manual_line_tl
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \iow_now:Nn { NV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_if_eq:nnTF { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\tofile{test.c}{{One}{Two}{Three}}<<EOF
/* #1, #2 */
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
  printf("#3",\n);
}
<<EOF

\end{document}

\tofile{\jobname.txt}{{One}{Two}{ASCII}}<<EOF
here is some nonsensical list of commands,
\unexpand\expandafter\gdef\indlude{#1}\def\expand\myOtherCrazyMacro
but who cares, I can even place my C code here
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
  printf("#2",\n);
}
this }}{{is some other illegal LaTeX code, which uses % percents, 
& other _^^^_ #3 stuff. 
<<EOF

\end{document}
```

The arguments here are three, specified as braced items in the second argument to `\tofile`:

```
\tofile{\jobname.txt}{ {One} {Two} {ASCII} }<<EOF
```

(spaces added for clarity, they are ignored).

Comment: Have you considered doing a serach-and-replace on the collected tokens rather than a retokenization? You could then allow `#` to be used in two ways: (i) if immediately followed by `1` or `2` to be replaced by the arguments, (ii) otherwise to be left as is.

Comment: @JosephWright That's for the evening. ;-) With `l3regex`, of course.