# Passing content as argument (or macro to be expanded) to verbatim environment

Tags: verbatim

Is it possible to custom what it's inside a `verbatim` environment? Suppose I want to print as verbatim something to be calculated on the fly, inserted in a kind of verbatim template. Think for example in printing an algorithm where the number of steps (or any other parameter) is to be calculated outside the `verbatim` environment, and then passed to it. I don't know if as a *macro* to be expanded or as an *argument*.

This is a kind of twist of this other [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211317/how-to-pass-parameters-to-sage-from-sagetex), but adapted to `verbatim` environment. I have the feeling that if the answer works for `verbatim`, so it will with `sagetex`.

Any ideas?

The MWE (please note the comment just below `\begin{verbatim}`:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\PassOptionsToPackage{T1}{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\pagestyle{empty} 

\begin{document}
\def\np{15}

\begin{verbatim}
np=\np #THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO GET, WHEN PRINTED, IT SHOULD BE np=15 
p1=0
pcoeffs=range(np+1)
x = var('x')
for i in range(np+1):
 pcoeffs[i]= Integer(randint(-8,8))
 p1=p1+pcoeffs[i]*x^i
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks like typesetting source code, being possible,for example,with `listings` and its `escape to LaTeX` method

Comment: Or `Verbatim` from `fancyvrb`

Comment: Thanks @ChristianHupfer, but the thing is that I'd want to know about a general method to do this, so it can also applies to sagetex (see link to my prior question)

Answer (score 6):

If your `verbatim` doesn't use backslashes and braces, you can do it with `fancyvrb`:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\pagestyle{empty} 

\begin{document}
\def\np{15}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
np=\np #THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO GET, WHEN PRINTED, IT SHOULD BE np=15 
p1=0
pcoeffs=range(np+1)
x = var('x')
for i in range(np+1):
 pcoeffs[i]= Integer(randint(-8,8))
 p1=p1+pcoeffs[i]*x^i
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you can use a variant of the code in my answer to [Partial expansion: macro arguments and nothing more](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155358/partial-expansion-macro-arguments-and-nothing-more)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex,verbatim}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\tofile}{m}
 {
  \manual_tofile:n { #1 }
 }

\iow_new:N \g_manual_tofile_write_stream
\tl_const:Nn \c_manual_specials_tl { \  \\ \{ \} \$ \& \# \^ \_ \% \~ }
\tl_new:N \l_manual_argument_tl
\tl_new:N \l_manual_line_tl
\seq_new:N \l_manual_arguments_seq
\int_new:N \l_manual_arguments_int

\cs_new_protected:Npn \manual_dospecials:
 {
  \tl_map_inline:Nn \c_manual_specials_tl
   {
    \char_set_catcode_other:N ##1
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \manual_tofile:n #1
 {
  \group_begin:
  \tex_endlinechar:D `\^^J
  \iow_open:Nn \g_manual_tofile_write_stream { #1 }
  \manual_tofile_aux:xw
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \manual_tofile_aux:nw #1 #2 ~%
 {% #1 is the list of arguments, #2 is the terminator
  \tl_set:Nn \l_manual_eof_tl { #2 }
  \tl_trim_spaces:N \l_manual_eof_tl
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_manual_arguments_seq { } { #1 }
  \int_set:Nn \l_manual_arguments_int { \seq_count:N \l_manual_arguments_seq }
  \manual_dospecials:
  \manual_readline:w
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \manual_tofile_aux:nw { x }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \manual_readline:w #1 ^^J
 {
  \str_if_eq:VnTF \l_manual_eof_tl { #1 }
   {
    \iow_close:N \g_manual_tofile_write_stream
    \group_end:
   }
   {
    \manual_replace_write:n { #1 }
    \manual_readline:w
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \manual_replace_write:n #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_manual_line_tl { #1 }
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \l_manual_arguments_int }
   {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_manual_argument_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_manual_arguments_seq { ##1 } }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \# ##1 } { \u{l_manual_argument_tl} } \l_manual_line_tl
   }
  \iow_now:NV \g_manual_tofile_write_stream \l_manual_line_tl
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \iow_now:Nn { NV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_if_eq:nnTF { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\np}{15}

\begin{document}
\tofile{\jobname.tmp}{{\np}}<<EOF
np=#1
p1=0
pcoeffs=range(np+1)
x = var('x')
for i in range(np+1):
 pcoeffs[i]= Integer(randint(-8,8))
 p1=p1+pcoeffs[i]*x^i
<<EOF
\verbatiminput{\jobname.tmp}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use `#1` and so on for denoting tokens to be substituted; the respective substitutions should be a list of braced arguments that are subject to full expansion.